# what is the workflow to program a .NET app that runs royalty-free on Raspberry PI with Windows IoT CORE?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

We want a royalty-free embedded solution on Raspberry PI to re-sell to customers.

Is the workflow something like:
1. Develop on desktop Visual Studio

2. Upload executable to windows IoT CORE on Raspberry PI
3. Ship to customer.

Comment: My reply answer your question? Feel free point out if I have misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I am assume you are talking about installing app not via Microsoft Store.

You workflow is working but there are some information to share with you:

- On Windows IoT Core, UWP is main application type supported. For non-UWP app supported and limitations you can reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore).
- Build your customer image and preinstall your app in it, then you can complete flash image and deploy app in one step. It is efficient when you have large number of devices.

More helpful information:

[Deploying an App with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appdeployment)

[Install your app on an IoT Core device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appinstaller)

[Update apps on your Windows 10 IoT Core devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps)